# Conflicting default and custom paths for nltk_data

Tags: python, macos, nltk

I understand that there should be two different directories for nltk_data: one for the default download and another one for the user's custom files.

In my macOS setup I have manually checked that all the default data packages are in `/usr/local/share/nltk_data`, and that is the outcome of `next(p for p in nltk.data.path if os.path.exists(p))`.

However, when I try to download another default package it doesn't go to that directory, but to `/Users/macbook/nltk_data`, where I understant that only my custom files should be. And testing the instalation for the default `nltk.corpus.brown.words()` fails because it looks for it in my custom path: `'No such file or directory: '/Users/macbook/nltk_data/corpora/brown/ca01'`

I am using Python 3.6.3, conda 4.4.8, and the outcome of `print(nltk.data.path)`is

> > > ['/Users/macbook/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data', '/Users/macbook/anaconda3/nltk_data', '/Users/macbook/anaconda3/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data']

Answer (score 3):

You can download any package like this:

```
nltk.download('treebank', download_dir='/home/username/data/treebank')
```

And you can tell nltk to look in a custom directory with this line:

```
nltk.data.path.append("path_to_custom_directory ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the first hint, to specify `download_dir`.

Comment: As for `nltk.data.path.append`, it doesn't solve the problem because both the default download (/usr/local/share/nltk_data) and my custom files (/Users/macbook/nltk_data) directories were already in paths, as you can see above. Nevertheless, `import nltk.data` only makes available .py files in the default, not in my custom directory.